# Structuring a SPA with modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, architecture, single-page-application

I'm working on a project where we're going to create a SPA that have to be composed of many modules.

The idea is that the application will have modules like:

- Dashboard
- Orders
- Customers
- Financial
- Others...

The idea is that any module can be a separated SPA, that will be consolidated by a MAIN APP, that will have the menu and will control the navigation between modules.

Based on that, we're plannig to struct our VS solution like these:

```
-- Solution
   /ModuleA
       /FrontEnd (single page application)
   /ModuleB
       /FrontEnd (single page application)
   /Main
       /Front (web project that will consolidated others)
```

As backend we'll use WEB.API (.net 4.5)

Our doubt is about what frameworks we have to use in these SPA (the actual plan is to use knockout.js, but we don't know if is the best choise) and how we can make this MAIN APP join the others modules dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout is good for more simple usages. It does not support SPA and modular approach. So you would have to handle it by yourself (or with help of some extensions).

I recommend you to take a look at frameworks that support SPA out-of-the-box. My favorite is [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), developed by Google.

It has great templating engine, supports IoC, [routing](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route), modules. You could easily make partial templates for your modules, put them into a separate files.

Comment: Thinking about our app, we plan to have something like Outlook.com, where you have a menu that you can open other module. Thinking about this scenario, we can see that they have a application for each module and each one run separated for others. In our case, we plan to have all in the same context, have all modules open in the same SPA. Do you think that it's a good scenario or is better do something like outlook.com?

Comment: With Angular you can create master controller and controllers specifically for each module. Angular is great for SPA, no matter what is your application about.

Comment: Ok. With this approach (master controller and controllers), I can create one controller per module and at the end, configure my product as business needs, right?

Comment: @TiagoSantos absolutely! You will find Angular very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

there are three key fact to build a SPA appliction.

1. client side routing
2. 2-way-binding
3. client side template

knockout it self only take care of 2-way-binding, it's easy to use and powerful, but it need a lot of friend, for example sammyjs for routing, handlebar for client side template

and when you want to make main app to interact other moudles dynamically, it become difficute to use knockout.

so my recommandation is angularjs, it's really powerful, and it take care of everything, it's worth to spend a little to have a look at

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using Knockout then have a look at [Durandaljs](http://durandaljs.com/) which is a SPA framework.  I have found it very easy to get up and running.